# How to compare and evaluate two int variables?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have two stored int variables a and b. 
I want to verify that b is bigger than a so the test to pass.

What would be the JS command in the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `assertEval | storedVars['a'] < storedVars['b'] | true`.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331214/1743880), removing the `storedVars` bit worked for me. I just used the var names in single quotes:

```
assertEval | '${a}' < '${b}' | true
```